Blazor chrome extension invoke C# method in BackgroundWorker.js
The idea is to  implement custom file chooser.
At simple BlazorBrowserExtension i'm trying to call a c# method  marked with the [JSInvokable] from  BackgroundWorker.js extension file.
According to documentation the project structure:

FilesChooser.cs
 public class FilesChooser
 {
     public FilesChooser(string? name)
     {
         Name = name ?? "No Name";
     }

     public string? Name { get; set; }

     [JSInvokable]
     public string GetHelloMessage() => $"Hello, {Name}!";
 }


JsInteropClasses3.cs
public class JsInteropClasses3
  {
      private readonly IJSRuntime js;

      public JsInteropClasses3(IJSRuntime js)
      {
          this.js = js;
      }

      public async ValueTask<string> CallHelloHelperGetHelloMessage(string? name)
      {
          using var objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(new FilesChooser(name));
          return await js.InvokeAsync<string>("GetHelloMessage", objRef);
      }
  }

And it works well on Index.razor
@code {
    private string? name;
    private string? result;
    private JsInteropClasses3? jsInteropClasses;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        jsInteropClasses = new JsInteropClasses3(JS);
    }

    private async Task TriggerDotNetInstanceMethod()
    {
        if (jsInteropClasses is not null)
        {
            result = await jsInteropClasses.CallHelloHelperGetHelloMessage(name);
        }
    }
}

But without embedded pages, when we have only events from some browser tabs. When i'm calling it from BackgroundWorker.js nothing hapends  (obviously falling with exseptions):
import * as _ from "/content/Blazor.BrowserExtension/lib/browser-polyfill.min.js";

browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const indexPageUrl = browser.runtime.getURL("index.html");
  browser.tabs.create({
    url: indexPageUrl
  });
});

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Callback for that request

    let rez = '';
    browser.invokeMethodsAsync = async (element) => {
        rez = await element.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetHelloMessage');
        sendResponse({ message: "Background has received that message " + rez});
    }

    return true;  // Add return true to fix the error. 
    
});


The event from some browser tab catches and redirected to chrome-core by ContentScript.js:
parent.addEventListener('message', function (event, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (event.data.type == 'notification') {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "openFileSelector" }, function (response) {
            console.log("send event");
            console.log(response);

            window.parent.postMessage(
                {
                    type: "notification_rez",
                    data: "2222"
                },
                "*",
            );
        });
    }
    
});


Is it possible. What can be done in this situation?

Do you have the JS code that you are executing in the index? If you create an object reference and pass it to JS, there should be a JS function with the name GetHelloMessage defined called according to your js.InvokeAsync<string>("GetHelloMessage", objRef).

No, index.js has no JS scripts, it doesn't visible to user . The idea is to overwrite file chooser. The event from application page intercepted in ContentScript.js and redirects to BackgroundWorker.js

I'm not sure what is the intended goal with calling to js.InvokeAsync because that method is intended for JS interop but you don't have any JS that handles the call from dotnet. As you understand, background doesn't have any UI, so it can't launch a file picker even if it receives a message from the content script.

No, event catches by ContentScript.js and redirects to BackgroundWorker.js which receives event to initiate tab by sendResponse({...});. This is a mechanism of chrome extension.  But the  rez = await element.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetHelloMessage'); in BackgroundWorker.js does not work. I hoped what building chrom app on Blazor platform will give such opportunity.

In your onmessage handler, you are declaring a function for browser.invokeMethodsAsync which is not invoked anywhere. Also, declaring a variable in the background does not allow the variable to be accessed from content script or any other context. The idea when building a chrome extension with Blazor is that if you can make it work in JS, you can also make it work in Blazor. If you can't make it work with just JS, using Blazor wouldn't help either.
